# Printing out a map, cannot convert const string to const char array

Tags: c++, string, dictionary

I need to loop through the map, and send a const char array to the function to print it, I tried to use string cpy but the result is the same, it cannot convert a const string to a char. What am i doint wrong?

```
std::map <std::string, int>::const_iterator end = scores.end();
std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator it;
for (it = scores.begin(); it != end; ++it)
{
    char initials[4];
    strcpy(initials,it->first);
    //std::string s = "";
    DrawString(screen, widthscreen/2 - (14*16)/4, heightscreen/2, initials,charsetsmall, 8);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use string member function **[string::c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)**

`it->first` returns `std::string` not underlying character data. To extract that you need to use the above member function.

You should use:

```
strcpy(initials,it->first.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) member of `std::string`.

```
DrawString(..., it->first.c_str(), ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
strcpy(initials,it->first);  //error
```

It should be this:

```
strcpy(initials,it->first.c_str()); //ok
```

Because `first` is `std::string`. You need to get the `const char*` which `std::string` stores by calling `c_str()`.

By the way, are you sure the maxium size of the string would be `4` including the null-character? Better use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy` as:

```
strncpy(initials,it->first.c_str(), 4); //better
```

The third argument is the number of characters to be copied from source to destination.

Comment: Better use `sizeof initials` instead of 4.

Comment: @KennyTM: That is okay, in this case, but if he changed the declaration to pointer, then BOOM!

Answer (score 1):

you have to convert string to char. Try

```
it->first.c_str();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strcpy(initials,it->first);
```

change it to

```
strcpy(initials, it->first.c_str());
```

But this may generate some security issues.